# calculating summary statistics by different ratings for a given price in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
price<-c(100,150,120,150,140,530)
rating<-c(2,2,1,1,1,3)
rooms<-c(1,1,1,1,2,4)
df<-data.frame(price,rating,rooms)

  price rating rooms
1   100      2     1
2   150      2     1
3   120      1     1
4   150      1     1
5   140      1     2
6   530      3     4
```

Bascially I want to find the summary statistics for price based on the rating. I tried the following by using split

```
split(df,rating)
```

But how do I then use the `summary` function  for prices based on each of the ratings?

Also is there a way I can do this without installing any packages?

Comment: What summary statistics, exactly? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all base R. You can use `by` to apply a function to a dataframe, broken up by a factor.

Convert `df$rating` to a factor first. Then assuming the summary stats you want are those returned by `summary`:

```
df$rating <- as.factor(df$rating)

by(df$price, df$rating, summary)

df$rating: 1
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  120.0   130.0   140.0   136.7   145.0   150.0 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$rating: 2
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  100.0   112.5   125.0   125.0   137.5   150.0 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$rating: 3
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    530     530     530     530     530     530
```

Answer (score 2):

To continue where you left off:

```
sapply(split(df$price, rating), summary)
               1     2   3
Min.    120.0000 100.0 530
1st Qu. 130.0000 112.5 530
Median  140.0000 125.0 530
Mean    136.6667 125.0 530
3rd Qu. 145.0000 137.5 530
Max.    150.0000 150.0 530
```

Answer (score 1):

`tapply(df$price, df$rating, mean)`